# Using mocked objects

Tags: android, mocking, mockito

I've just started unit testing on Android with Mockito - how do you get the class that you are testing on to use the mocked class/object instead of the regular class/object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By injecting the dependency:

```
public class ClassUnderTest
    private Dependency dependency;

    public ClassUnderTest(Dependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    // ...
}

...

 Dependency mockDependency = mock(Dependency.class);
 ClassUnderTest c = new ClassUnderTest(mockDependency);
```

You can also use a setter to inject the dependency, or even inject private fields directly using the `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` annotations (read [the javadoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html) for a detailed explanation of how they work).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use @InjectMocks for the class you writing the test.

   `@InjectMocks
   private EmployManager manager;`
2. Then you can use @Mock for the class you are mocking. This will be the dependency class.

   `@Mock
   private EmployService service;`
3. Then write a setup method to make things available for your tests.

> ```
> @Before
> public void setup() throws Exception {
>   manager = new EmployManager();
>   service = mock(EmployService.class);
>   manager.setEmployService(service);
>   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
> }
> ```

Then write your test.

```
@Test
public void testSaveEmploy() throws Exception {
    Employ employ = new Employ("u1");
    manager.saveEmploy(employ);

    // Verify if saveEmploy was invoked on service with given 'Employ'
    // object.
    verify(service).saveEmploy(employ);

    // Verify with Argument Matcher
    verify(service).saveEmploy(Mockito.any(Employ.class));
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201643/mock-injection-using-mockito-android. Thanks