# Mock injection using Mockito - Android

Tags: android, mockito

I've just started unit testing on Android. I've tried testing a simple calculator app and I'm stuck on a problem regarding injecting mocks.

As per my understanding there are two ways of injecting mocks. Using dependency injections or using annotations like `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`.

So here's my problem:

My calculator class uses another class **Vars** that holds the default value of the variables I intend to use. This is the class I want to mock so that I can use other variables instead of the default ones.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CalcActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<CalcActivity> {

private Intent in;
private Button btnAdd,btnSub,btnMul,btnDiv,btnDef;
private TextView res;
@InjectMocks
private CalcActivity mActivity;
@Mock
private Vars mockVar;


public CalcActivityTest() {
    super(CalcActivity.class);
}

@Before
protected void setUp() throws Exception{

    super.setUp();
    in = new Intent(getInstrumentation().getTargetContext(),CalcActivity.class);
    in.putExtra("num1", 20.0);
    in.putExtra("num2",20.0);
    startActivity(in, null, null);
    mockVar = mock(Vars.class);
    mockVar.setn1(20);
    mockVar.setn2(40);

    mActivity = getActivity();

}
```

However when I try using mockVar for any of the operations, the default value stored inside Vars is used instead that of mockVar which probably means that the mocked variable is not injected properly. Can anyone point out where I've went wrong ?

EDIT : Updating question with code from CalcActivity

```
package com.example.advancedcalc;

import com.example.advancedcalc.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalcActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button btnAdd,btnSub,btnMul,btnDiv,btnDefault;
private TextView res;

private double n1,n2;

private Vars var;

public CalcActivity(Vars var){
    this.var  = var;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calc);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    btnSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sub);
    btnMul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mul);
    btnDiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.div);

    btnDefault = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDef);

    res = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    n1 = extras.getDouble("num1");
    n2 = extras.getDouble("num2");

    var = new Vars();

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSub.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMul.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDiv.setOnClickListener(this);

    btnDefault.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.calc, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.add: 
        res.setText(String.valueOf(add(n1,n2)));
        break;
    case R.id.sub: 
        res.setText(String.valueOf(sub(n1,n2)));
        break;
    case R.id.mul: 
        res.setText(String.valueOf(mul(n1,n2)));
        break;
    case R.id.div: 
        res.setText(String.valueOf(div(n1,n2)));
        break;
    case R.id.btnDef:
        n1 = var.getn1();
        n2 = var.getn2();
    }

}

public double add(double n1,double n2){
    return n1+n2;
}
public double sub(double n1,double n2){
    return n1-n2;
}
public double mul(double n1,double n2){
    return n1*n2;
} 
public double div(double n1,double n2){
    return n1/n2;
}
}
```

Comment: What's the code of CalcActivity? Why are you re-assigning a new mock to mockVars in the setUp() method, since the Mock annotation already creates one? What does `getActivity()` do?

Comment: `getActivity()` returns the Activity under test. I'm re-assigning mockVars because `mockVar.set()` returns a null pointer exception without it. Updating the question with code from CalcActivity.

Comment: The activity under test should be   `mActivity`, since that's what Mockito has injected with `mockVar` (the one created before you reinitialized it in your setUp() method). Re-read the doc of those annotations. You shouldn't reaffect anything to these variables, else the annotations don't serve any purpose.

Comment: I need to use `getActivity()` because i need to call `findViewById()` method to initialize different UI elements in my CalcActivity class. Not using `getActivity()` would return a null pointer exception for all my UI elements.

Comment: Then you should inject mock UI elements, or create a Spy over the real activity returned by getActivity(), and not a mock.

Answer (score 3):

1. Since you have already used @Mock for Vars class, you don't need to use -

   `mockVar = mock(Vars.class);`
2. You need to stub the calls on you mock object. Instead of -

   `mockVar.setn1(20);
   mockVar.setn2(40);`

You need to stub your getters (I am sure there will be methods like getn1() in Vars class) -

```
Mockito.when(mockVar.getn1()).thenReturn(20);
Mockito.when(mockVar.getn2()).thenReturn(40);
```

And then write your test.

Comment: I made the changes as you suggested and using `Mockito.when(mockVar.getn1()).thenReturn(20);` returns a null pointer exception.

Comment: Are you using MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); in setup() method. You should use this before any stub.

Comment: I've added it now. The mock object still isnt getting injected. My class is still using Var instead of mockVar.

Comment: @InjectMocks only works on members annotated with @Inject. You only create a mocked Vars, but not inject into the CalcActivity instance. You should add a `setVars(Vars var)` in the CalcActivity class and invoke it with the mocked vars in the test case's `setUp()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is the classical problem where people confuse the notion of partial mocks introduced by Mockito.

You need to inject this mocked Var dependency in your Activity and this is tough since Android is managing the entire life cycle of activities.
So in order to achieve your desired outcome you either use Dagger framework from Square or you use Service Locator Pattern if you don't want to introduce third party dependencies in your app.

Here is a more detailed article into Service Locator Pattern for injecting dependencies in your Activity:  [Improving Android Testing with Service Locator Pattern](http://bit.ly/1SS7ukC)